# Qual a melhor maneira de criar um socket com multiplas conexões que vá realizar uma ação em outra API

Tags: php, web-service, socket, websocket

Estou criando um webservice com PHP, para receber conexões TCP, para isso abri um socket que recebe multiplas conexeões. Porém quando um dispositivo se conectar no servidor terei que ir buscar em outra API de um terceiro (via HTTP), e essa API retorna os dados em cerca de 3 segundos. (É bastante o volume de dados)
Para que não funcione como uma fila a única maneira que encontrei de fazer isso é com threads, mas não sei se é possível retornar os dados para o cliente conectado no servidor via thread, gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira melhor de fazer isso.

```
    <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting as it comes in. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = '127.0.0.1';

$port = 10000;

// create a streaming socket, of type TCP/IP
$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);

socket_bind($sock, $address, $port);

socket_listen($sock);

// create a list of all the clients that will be connected to us..
// add the listening socket to this list
$clients = array($sock);

while (true)
{
    // create a copy, so $clients doesn't get modified by socket_select()
    $read = $clients;
    $write = null;
    $except = null;

    // get a list of all the clients that have data to be read from
    // if there are no clients with data, go to next iteration
    if (socket_select($read, $write, $except, 0) < 1)
        continue;

    // check if there is a client trying to connect
    if (in_array($sock, $read))
    {
        $clients[] = $newsock = socket_accept($sock);

        socket_getpeername($newsock, $ip, $port);
        echo "New client connected: {$ip}\n";

        $key = array_search($sock, $read);
        unset($read[$key]);
    }

    // loop through all the clients that have data to read from
    foreach ($read as $read_sock)
    {
        // read until newline or 1024 bytes
        // socket_read while show errors when the client is disconnected, so silence the error messages
        $data = @socket_read($read_sock, 4096, PHP_BINARY_READ);

        // check if the client is disconnected
        if ($data === false)
        {
            // remove client for $clients array
            $key = array_search($read_sock, $clients);
            unset($clients[$key]);
            echo "client disconnected.\n";
            continue;
        }

        $data = trim($data);

        if (!empty($data))
        {
            $msg = json_decode($data,true); 

            if ($msg['requisicao'] == "01"){
                $lista_debitos = new ListaDebitos($read_sock,$msg);
                $lista_debitos->start();

                $key = array_search($read_sock, $clients);
                unset($clients[$key]);
            }   
        }

    } // end of reading foreach
}

// close the listening socket
socket_close($sock);
```

Comment: Estes dados não podem ser fracionados?

Comment: Não, mas mesmo que pudessem, continuaria funcionando como uma fila e o problema persistiria, pois a previsão é que o webservice vá receber muitas conexões em alguns momentos.

Comment: E como você está desenvolvendo esse webservice? Consegue postar o código?

Comment: Você esta falando de socket ou websocket , são levemente parecidas mais totalmente diferentes os tipos de tecnologias, e as abordagens tabem para se trabalhar

Comment: Inseri o código @FilipeL.Constante.

Comment: @GabrielSousa Socket mesmo.